Is this process safe? "ClipboardMonitor"
This process is displaying on my taskbar as "ClipboardMonitor".  It seems related to a remote desktop client, but that is just a guess.
My question is what is this tracking and where is the output going?
Here is the command line for the process:
/opt/TSPrintClient/java/bin/java -classpath /opt/TSPrintClient/commons-codec-1.10.jar:/opt/TSPrintClient/commons-io-2.4.jar:/opt/TSPrintClient/sun.misc.BASE64Decoder.jar:/opt/TSPrintClient/TSPrintClient.jar MonitorClipboard


Edit:
As Rinzwind explained, I did install it myself.  I didn't realize "/opt/" = not used by the OS. Thank you for pointing that out!
Regarding "the answer is 'you need to trust the creator/maintainer of this software': Yes, thank you for pointing this out... in my defense, although I install from sources I trust, it doesn't mean I know every modification that source / install is doing to my system.

you installed it yourself (/opt/ is NOT used by the OS), and any 3rd party software the answer is "you need to trust the creator/maintainer of this software"

A quick Google search shows that TSPrintClient is part of an offering of the company Terminalworks. They do not appear to provide any source code, or much transparency at all, on the workings of the solution.
They would need to indicate how their software works - if you are the administrator/sole user of that system and installed it, then you should contact them directly. If your system is administered by someone else, I would suggest contacting that administrator first.
